# Small typo in my initializer list causes unspeakable pain

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, compiler-warnings

So, I just got through with a grueling multi-hour debug session of a large server application.  The error eventually came down to a barely noticeable typo in a constructor.  Basically, it was something like:

```
template <class T>
class request_handler
{
    public:

    request_handler(T& request, Log& error_log) 
      : m_request(m_request), m_error_log(error_log)
     { 
       /*... some code ... */
     }

    ...
};
```

See the bug?  Well, I didn't.  The problem is a small typo in the initializer list: `m_request(m_request)` is assigning an uninitialized reference to itself.  Obviously, it's supposed to read `m_request(request)`.

Now, the member variable `m_request` is of type `T&`.  So - is there some reason the compiler didn't warn me that I was using an uninitialized variable here?

Using GCC 4.6 with the `-Wall` flag, if I say:

```
int x;
x = x;
```

...it will issue a warning: `warning: ‘x’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]`

So, why didn't the compiler warn me when I assigned `m_request` to itself: essentially assigning an uninitialized reference to itself?  It would have saved me hours of annoyance.

Comment: Did you compile this with full optimizations enabled (-O3)? The compiler will only notice some of these mistakes when it actually does data-flow analysis.
Also consider just dropping the m_ prefix. `foo(T bar) : bar(bar)` is perfectly well-defined.

Comment: At first I was compiling with optimizations.  But while debugging, I was compiling with the `-g3` flag so I could use the debugger.  Even with the `g3` flag it didn't issue any warning.

Comment: I wouldn't expect `-g3` to cause this warning anyway, all it does is dump your symbols.

Comment: I believe "small typo causes unspeakable pain" is the official motto of C++.  ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Annoying bug to track down. It turns out, you don't even need templates to silently fail on this one. This'll do the trick:

```
class C {
        int a, b;
public:
        C(int t, int z) : a(a), b(z) { };
};
```

Clang warns on this with `-Wuninitialized`.

*Good news for gcc folks*: according to gnu's bugzilla, [gcc 4.7.0 has fixed this](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18016).

**Update**

On gcc 4.7.0, add `-Wself-init` to get this warning (verified by [sbellef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155231/sbellef)):

> tst.cc: In constructor ‘C::C(int, int)’: tst.cc:4:9: warning: ‘C::a’ is initialized with itself [-Wuninitialized]

Comment: Curiously, I don't see the bug documentation mentioning member references, but maybe the fix handles both cases the same.

Comment: The GCC on my system `gcc version 4.7.0 20120505 (prerelease) (GCC)` does not seem to report the error. On the other hand, clang reports it properly: `clang++ -Wall -c tst.cc
tst.cc:4:29: warning: field is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
        C(int t, int z) : a(a), b(z) { };
                            ^
1 warning generated.`

Comment: @sbellef, Did you use -Wself-init ?

Comment: No I had used `-Wall` only. Now if I add `-Winit-self` I get: `tst.cc: In constructor ‘C::C(int, int)’:
tst.cc:4:9: warning: ‘C::a’ is initialized with itself [-Wuninitialized]`

Answer (score 3):

I like to use the trick of using the same name for the members as the constructor parameters.

```
template <class T>
request_handler(T& request, Log& error_log) 
 : request(request), error_log(error_log)
{ 
  /*... some code ... */
}
```

This will always prevent the error. You have to be careful though as in the function body `request` refers to argument, not the member. This of course doesn't matter for simple types such as references,  but I don't recommend it for classes.

Comment: That's why it should be `T const& request` - you only need the argument to initialize `this->request`, you're not going to modify it. If your use case is more complex, then I recommend against this. But if you're using this pattern consistently in the simple case, the additional benefit is that the pattern becomes recognizable. "Oh, that parameter `Foo` is there just to initialize `Foo`. I'm looking into `Bar` so I don't need to care about `Foo`"